# Determine range of proportional gain with given overshoot

Tags: control-theory, root-locus

I have given the open-loop transfer function
$$
G_{ol} = 1.42 \frac{(s+3)^2+6^2}{(s-1)(s+2)((s+4)^2+4^2)}
$$
The task I was given is determining the range of the proportional gain, which makes the overshoot less than 10%.

I know that the overshoot is calculated using the formula
$$
\delta=e^{-\frac{\pi}{\tan \varphi}}<0.1
$$
$$
\varphi < \arctan \left(-\frac{\pi}{\ln(0.1)}\right) \approx 53.76°
$$
which also gives me the damping ratio
$$
-\frac{\pi}{\tan \varphi} = -\frac{\pi \xi}{\sqrt{1-\xi^2}} \to \xi = 0.59
$$
So every pole with a higher damping ratio than that would fulfill my condition.

The root-locus of this transfer function is given as
[image: Root Locus of the open-loop transfer function]
My question now is how do I determine the range of the proportional gain, which fulfills this condition?
I think what I would need is the natural frequency for determining the poles which have this damping ratio.
The characteristic equation of the closed-loop transfer function would be
$$
1+KG_{ol} = (s-1)(s+2)\left((s+4)^2+4^2\right)+1.42K\left((s+3)^2+6^2\right)=0
$$
And I'm stuck here.

Using Matlab, I got the two poles, which have an overshoot of exactly 10%
$$
p_{1,2} = -0.343 \pm 0.47j
$$
which gives me a proportional gain of
$$
K = 1.18
$$
But how do I get there? I would like to not use Matlab and understand how this is calculated.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: The root locus indcates that your system seems to have only two dominant poles (the ones originally at 1 and -2). Since you have a value of zeta already available with you, you can draw the constant damping lines corresponding to that zeta. They are two straight lines cos(theta) = -zeta (Ref https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/second-order-system). Draw such a line. The parts of the root locus intersecting it and to the left of the lines are the gain ranges you are searching for. Not posting as an answer since this is an approximation method due to assumption of dominant poles.

Comment: I already knew the method with just determining the angle and drawing the line to determine the poles which serve as a limit for my conditions. But I was thinking there would be a mathematical approach, without the necessity of drawing the root-locus and then just "seeing" what poles I would need.
Nevertheless AJN, thanks for your reply ;)

Comment: What about doing it the hard way? Take inverse laplace transform of the step response; i.e; (1/s) * Gcl to get the analytic expression. Then find the expression for maxima of the step response in terms of K. This result will be an exact solution.